# How node.js is build?

Tags: python, node.js

I am beginner in node.js.

I came to this question while I am watching video - [Ryan Dahl: Original Node.js presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztspvPYybIY).

In between 18:10 to 18:25 minutes,

> Ryan Dahl said - "there is no real dependencies other than python".

1) From this, can I infer that node.js is dependent on python or it is built in python?

2) What are the base languages for node.js?

3) Can someone explain me about the compiler of node.js? What kind of compiler it is using? How it is working?

Comment: He was talking about installation wizard which requires Python just for installation. Node is built on top of libuv, v8, etc. which are implemented in C/C++.

Comment: read [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) - and you'll see that to install *some* `native addon modules for Node.js` requires a lot more than just python - but that's not a real dependency of node

Comment: I am not convinced with what you are saying guys. May be because of I don't have much knowledge about this. Guys can you suggest articles or blogs or any kind of material from which I get knowledge about how node.js is build on (not about what is nodejs or what can I do with nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

node.js is not dependent on python.  It may been in 2009 when the presentation was given.